# "people you may know" sql query

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm working on a "people you may know" feature. I have two tables:

USERS
id
email
name
etc

FRIENDSHIPS
user_id
friend_id

For each friendship I make two records. Say users 7 and 9 become friends... I would make a record where user_id=7,friend_id=9 and another where user_id=9, friend_id=7 in the friendships table.

How would I make a sql query that suggests people I'm likely to know based on friends of my friends? I also want it ordered based on the most mutual friends.

Comment: if user 7 and 9 are friends, why do you want to have records storing the same data. I think you need to work on your table structure a little. Just thinking out loud, maybe a friendshipid column and two userid columns

Comment: @Pavanred It's much easier to return a list of friends that way. I can say "select friend_id from friendships where user_id = 9"... Much easier than the alternatives.

Comment: So you are rebuilding facebook?  :-)

Comment: @Chris lol... no, just private social networks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select u.id, u.email, u.name, u.etc
-- Get all my friends
from Friendships as f1
-- Get their friends
inner join Friendships as f2
    on f1.friend_id = f2.user_id
-- Get their friends User information
inner join Users as u
    on f2.friend_id = u.id
where f1.user_id = @userId
```

Would be where I would start.

Comment: I'm looking for friends of friends, not just friends.

Comment: It's so annoying that SQL comments aren't highlighted here as such :(

Comment: Looks good, how would I order it based on the greatest amount of friends in common?

Comment: Dear Mr. Justin Niessner. Can you please make any comments for `ordering by number of mutual friends`? I really need to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select friend_id from friendships where user_id IN (select friendid from freindships where userid = <userid>)
```

Considering user 7 and 9 are friends. For user 7, this query would give you the list of friends of user 9.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(select distinct friendsOfFriends.friends_id, count(1) as mutualfriends
  from FRIENDSHIPS friendsOfFriends
 inner join FRIENDSHIPS friends ON friends.friend_id = friendsOfFriends.user_id
  where friends.user_id = @myuserid
  group by friendsOfFriends.friends_id) t
order by mutualfriends desc
```

Comment: obviously this will give the ordered list of users, but not the other details - you will need another join for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query below;

**Query**:

```
Select * from [USERS] U where id not in 
((select F.friend_id as id from [FRIENDSHIPS] f where f.user_id='" + Session["UserId"] + "' and f.Status=1)
union (select F.user_id as id from [FRIENDSHIPS] f where f.friend_id='" + Session["UserId"] + "' and f.Status=1)
union (select F.friend_id as id from [FRIENDSHIPS] f where f.user_id='" + Session["UserId"] + "' and f.Status=0)
union (select F.friend_id as id from [FRIENDSHIPS] f where f.user_id='" + Session["UserId"] + "' and f.Status=2))
and U.id !='" + Session["UserId"] + "'
```

NOTE: Status may be "**1**", "**0**", "**2**" as a default parameters. The meaning of them are;

**1**: Confirmed
**0**: Not Confirmed yet
**2**: Denied

I wrote query code above considering by these parameters. Yours may be like this, too.

Take it easy!